# Куда записываются локальные константы с++

Tags: c++, const

Насколько я знаю, глобальные константы хранятся в `.data` - сегменте, в `read-only` секции. Но что насчёт локальных констант? По идее они должны храниться на стеке, но неужели на стеке есть такая же `read-only`-секция?

Comment: Да нигде они не хранятся, если нет повода их хранить.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/583076/9210255

Comment: в read-only хранятся константы времени компиляции, то бишь куски исполняемого файла

Comment: Если некоторые константы хранятся в `read-only` секции, то это ещё не означает, что любые константы должны храниться в `read-only` секции. [Пример](https://ideone.com/JCZVi2) изменения константной переменной (строго говоря, поведение приведённой программы не определено, это просто демонстрация идеи).

Comment: Связанные вопросы: [Изменение констант базовых типов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/436592), [Как хранятся в памяти литералы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/618499).

Comment: @wololo, тогда уже получается что "константа" не является константой раз ее можно изменить. А если мне нужно гарантировать ее неизменяемость не только во время компиляции программы, но и на этапе её выполнения, получается что она обязательно должна быть со статической продолжительностью хранения, верно?

Comment: `const` - это помощь программисту, чтобы он не наделал ошибок. Компилятор имеет право на константные переменные делать очень много оптимизации вплоть до отсутствия этой переменной в памяти, она остаётся только в ассемблерном коде. Вот здесь константа уже не меняется. Обратный пример для @wololo [Константа не изменилась](https://godbolt.org/z/onr4ejrcK)

Comment: `получается что "константа" не является константой раз ее можно изменить` Просто программа содержит неопределённое поведение — все гарантии стандарта языка снимаются, в частности, больше не гарантируется неизменность констант. `А если мне нужно гарантировать ее неизменяемость` Тогда не допускайте неопределённого поведения. Вот [другой пример](https://ideone.com/ljxmZx). Здесь прямой модификации константного объекта нет, но есть другое UB, которое также приводит к изменению константы.

Comment: `если мне нужно гарантировать ее неизменяемость ... получается что она обязательно должна быть со статической продолжительностью хранения`. Ещё раз: попытка модификации константного объекта вызывает неопределённое поведение, все гарантии снимаются, результат выполнения программы никак не специфицируется. Гарантировать, что модификация статической константы приведёт к «падению программы» (если, конечно, ваша цель добиться такого поведения) нельзя. Может упадёт, [а может и нет](https://ideone.com/qj2vA3).

Comment: *"А если мне нужно гарантировать ее неизменяемость не только во время компиляции программы, но и на этапе её выполнения..."* - ... то вы же сами и должны это гарантировать. В С++ за то, что объекты с const квалификатором не изменяются во время выполнения (как и за многие другие вещи) отвечает программист. Если хотите гарантий, то используйте Ada/SPARK с верификацией.